# HttpURLConnection downloading data is too slow

Tags: android, http, download, httpurlconnection

I've made an application that is going to download data from youtube videos and process it to get the Video Image and Title and Video Quality but it's taking too much time and the application is Buggy there is my code:

```
package amaigh.halzoun;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int contentlenght;
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {

                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                contentlenght = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (contentlenght == 200) {
                    InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                    int data = reader.read();

                    while (data != -1) {

                        char current = (char) data;

                        result += current;

                        data = reader.read();

                    }

                    return result;
                }
                else
                    return "Connection Lost";

            }
            catch(Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                return "Failed";

            }


        }

    }
    public class ImageDownload extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try{
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                Log.i("DOWNLOAD IMAGE URL:" ,url.toString());
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                return image;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void Start (View view)
    {
        String Url = "";
        ImageView VideoImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        EditText URLInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.URL);
        Url = URLInput.getText().toString();
        Log.i("Original URL: ", Url);
        Url = Url.replace("watch?v=","embed/");
        Log.i("Title URL: ", Url);
        DownloadTask GetTitle = new DownloadTask();
        String result = "";
        String VideoUrl = Url.replace("https://www.youtube.com/embed/","https://i.ytimg.com/vi/");
        VideoUrl += "/hqdefault.jpg";
        ImageDownload imageDownloader = new ImageDownload();
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {

            result = GetTitle.execute(Url).get();
            image = imageDownloader.execute(VideoUrl).get();
            VideoImage.setImageBitmap(image);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        GetTitle(result);
        Url = URLInput.getText().toString();
        DownloadTask GetVideoInfo = new DownloadTask();
        result = "";

        try {

            result = GetVideoInfo.execute(Url).get();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        Log.i("Resultat: ", result);

    }
    public void GetTitle(String Content){
        String searchString = "<title>(.*?)</title>";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(searchString);
        TextView VideoTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.VideoTitle);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(Content);
        while (m.find()){
            Log.i("Title: ", m.group(1));
            VideoTitle.setText(m.group(1));
        }
    }
    public void GetInfo(String Content){
        ArrayList<String> VideoQuality = new ArrayList<>();
        String searchString = "quality_label=(.*?)p";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(searchString);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(Content);
        while (m.find()){
            VideoQuality.add(m.group(0).replace("quality_label=",""));
        }
        int a = 0;

        VideoQuality.remove(0);
        VideoQuality.remove(2);
        VideoQuality.remove(4);
        VideoQuality.remove(6);
        VideoQuality.remove(8);
        VideoQuality.remove(10);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,VideoQuality);
        Spinner Spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Please tell me what i've done wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use Restful Web Services of Spring may be it can help you by decreasing processing time and increase the efficiency.
And you get for object or others method to download the data from a webUrl, 
it also decrease the headache of parsing the data and also decrease the size of code.

For reference go to : https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Comment: I need to use HttpUrlConnection to do this

Comment: @amazighhalzoun RestFul web services also uses HttpUrlConnection in background so you can you it, It will be more helpful for you and you would be love to work with Rest Services